# How to fix the CSS of a JQuery Slide Element

Tags: jquery, css, slider, mousehover

I have built a jquery slide on hover event.  At the bottom on the page, I have the slider element that will expand when the mouse hovers the element.  I have a tab that will stick out the top of the element to remind the user that the functionality exists.  This tab is causing me many problems and when you hover over the tab, the element will expand and contract repeatedly.  I have tried editing the CSS and it worked correctly when I removed margin-top but this is not how the design was intended.  I have tried to add a DIV to solve this as well which did not work.  Can you help me get the tab to work correctly?

I am using JQuery 1.5.1

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>   
  <div class="Livwidget">
  <div class="tab"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.Livwidget{
  background: #000;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
 }


 .tab{
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: -30px;
  width: 135px;
 }
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".Livwidget").hover(makeTall,makeShort);
    }); // close document.ready

    function makeTall(){  $(this).animate({"height":250},350);}
    function makeShort(){ $(this).animate({"height":5},350);}
</script>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.  I have spent hours playing around to try to fix this and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: When you hover over the tab, perhaps 'makeTall' is causing you not to be hovering the tab, triggering 'makeShort', which causes you to hover again?

Answer (score 1):

Add an if/else statment for a variable called `var activeAnimation`, it should be declared as `0` outside of your script, then only allow animation if it is `0`, as soon as it starts the animation set `activeAnimation = 1`, then at the end of your animation, make the callback include a function to make `activeAnimation = 0`

Comment: Great idea.  I tried to code this myself but I only been coding a month so I have not gotten good enough to code JS out side of using jquery.  You can explain how to do this in a little more detail?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Qsqrc/

Comment: The main problem with your script is that you detect mouse activity with an element that you pull away. So you trigger a mouseleave event because you pull the rug out from under it. Your best bet is to have the mouse detection on an object that stays under the mouse.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem entirely.  The tab needs to be part of the div which is causing the problem.